# XPath getting nested values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<List><Item><Owner><v>0009501</v><Owner_Valid><v>AC704795228F4A6FA697FC99C7F8F487</v></Owner_Valid></Owner><MaintenenceTermWeeks><v>0</v></MaintenenceTermWeeks></Item></List>
```

I need to get each Item as a record, without the tags and flattened, like this:

Item:

```
Owner: 0009501
Owner_Valid: AC704795228F4A6FA697FC99C7F8F487
MaintenenceTermWeeks: 0
```

This is not working for me using XPath /List/Item

Comment: How about `/List/Item/*`?

Comment: In what sense is it "not working"? What result did you actually get, and how does it differ from what you wanted? The `/List/Item` XPath expression should select one node from your sample XML, the `<Item>` element. If you want to do formatted output of the child elements and their values, XPath is not the best tool, but you could do it (for a single Item) using `concat(...)`. If you have XPath 2.0, you could do that for multiple Items.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the C# class representation of your XML:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Owner_Valid")]
    public class Owner_Valid {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="v")]
        public string V { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Owner")]
    public class Owner {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="v")]
        public string V { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Owner_Valid")]
        public Owner_Valid Owner_Valid { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="MaintenenceTermWeeks")]
    public class MaintenenceTermWeeks {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="v")]
        public string V { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Item")]
    public class Item {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Owner")]
        public Owner Owner { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="MaintenenceTermWeeks")]
        public MaintenenceTermWeeks MaintenenceTermWeeks { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="List")]
    public class List {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Item")]
        public Item Item { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The next thing that you need to do is to deserialize the XML to C# object:

```
List list= null;
string path = "list.xml";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
owner= (List)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```